# Visual Studio 2003 not rebuilding, can I only build one dll and transfer it to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2003

Basically it's in the title. There's a bug in a VS2003 website that needs to be fixed but it is not letting us rebuild the entire project and the bug needs to be fixed immediately. Is it possible to only rebuild the dll that has the bug in it, transfer it to the server that's hosting the website and have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using strong names, you should be able to recompile just the one assembly, yes.

However, if you are signing your assemblies, no, you will have to rebuild all of the DLLs.

If you just need to rebuild everything, use the "Rebuild" command, or manually delete all "bin" and "obj" folders in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it's an isolated change (ie, doesn't change the signatures of any public methods) you should be able to build and deploy a single dll.